# Typescript Error Object is of type 'unknown'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-final-form

New to Typescript and can't figure this error I am getting. I am using final form and pushing items into an array. I can console.log the values and see the array and the items in the array. But when I pass this to my child component I keep getting the error:
`Object is of type 'unknown`

Parent Component

```
<Form 
  onSubmit={onFormSubmit} 
  initialValues={{ items: [{ item: '' }, { item: '' }]}} 
  mutators={{ ...arrayMutators }} 
>
<List values={values} />
//no TS error
```

Child Component

```
//List.tsx

<Button disabled={values.items.length === 10}>Add item</Button>
//TS error for values.items (Object is of type 'unknown')
```

Type Declaration:

```
values: Record<string, unknown>;
```

Comment: Well, you declared `values` as `Record<string, unknown>`, so `values.items` is `unknown`, unless you check its type explicitly. How this property is used inside the component? Can you declare its type more strictly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if `values` types are `unknown`, you can't use `items.length` at the `List` component, because `items` is `undefined` under the hood.

Comment: You can try something like:  
`<Button disabled={(values.items as Array<unknown>).length === 10}>Add item</Button>`